# Automatic OpenId access token refresh on expiration

Tags: open-liberty

I'm trying to figure it out if OpenLiberty (Relying party impl) is able to automatically refresh the OpenId access token once it is expired by calling the token endpoint with the refresh token? I had a look at the code and I can't find any code indicating that it is doing this. Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more context or code to help someone provide assistance. Mode examples and web links are very helpful when providing questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the auto refresh of accessTokens using the refreshTokens is not supported in Liberty. You can open an issue.

--Ajay

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now open in Open Liberty for this:
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/15968

Are you looking for this support for the implicit flow with a browser-based SPA app or a basic/authentication flow (RP to OP)?

Comment: For the Authorization Code Flow

Answer (score 0):

Liberty does not automatically refresh access_token with refresh_token. However, there is an option to ensure access_token is always valid whenever browser is refreshed. The way it works is like this: Liberty set browser security session time to be the lesser of id_token life time and access_token, and redirect user to OP for login if session expires. To do this, you set following properties: disableLtpaCookie ="true", reAuthnOnAccessTokenExpire="true", and optional property reAuthnCushion=.

Comment: yes, indeed it could work if I wasn't in a Vaadin app which is Ajax based. So basically, it will just redirect the current ajax request and this will cause a "Comunication problem" error forcing the end user to refresh the browser in order to continue. That's acceptable when an http session expires but not every time the access token expires. So, unfortunately, not a solution in my case.